# How to get live Indian real-time stock market data ( tick wise )

Tags: .net, flutter, finance, stock

I have a flutter app which has a .net backend in where I want to show the stock market real time data. I couldn't find any documentation for this stock market api. How can I acheive it ?

I tried using the yahoo finance but there wasn't any documentation from there web page i found they get the data from their websocket to which I can successfully connect but I don't know how to decode the response as there is no documentation for it.

Comment: As far as I know, Yahoo Finance doesn't offer API service anymore.
Try to find another website providing live data (there are many)

Comment: @Emanuele Can you please tell me a few live data providers as I am having a hard time finding some working endpoints.

Comment: They are all working (some of them with more documentation)... It obviously depends a lot on the amount of money do you want to spend, if you need historical records or only  live, if you need crypto or only stocks... I think that searching on google "Stock market API"  will provide enough results

Comment: I have tried so many sites but couldn't find any site where they allow users to show data publicly on their my own platform.